# People who treat living things with kindness and love: word/term

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word (or term) that specifically and exactly describes someone who loves all living things. I'd prefer something that isn't extremely technical (a word/term hat is mostly understood) but at the same time, not too simple (i.e. *animal-lover*).

I don't think context is necessary in this case, but regardless...

> before going to bed, a teenage girl visits the washroom where she finds a moth. Rather than killing it, she gently releases it outside.

Perhaps this can be described as **kind**, but I'm looking for something that specifically refers to a *love or kindness towards beings of life* (except for maybe single-cell organisms).

Comment: “vegan”, perhaps? 

Comment: How is not killing a moth treating it with love? Can you love something that cannot love you back? I think not. Not all living things are capable of loving or recognizing "kindness".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone *[compassionate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/compassionate)* cares for other people and perhaps for animals (but not, I think, for single-celled organisms or plants, so not **all** living things).

Someone who feels an emotional connection with other things can be described as *[empathetic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/empathetic)*. Such a person can be called an *[empath](http://www.drjudithorloff.com/Free-Articles/emotional-empath-EF.htm)*.

Answer (score 2):

She may be described as:

- ***[affectionate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/affectionate)*** : showing, indicating, or characterized by affection or love; fondly tender
- ***[Tender](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tender#tender)*** : Showing gentleness, kindness, and affection
- ***[Benevolent](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/benevolent?q=Benevolent)*** : Well meaning and kindly

or

- ***[Humane](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/humane?q=Humane)*** : Having or showing compassion or benevolence

Comment: Also **commiserative**: expressing or feeling sympathy or pity; sympathizing.

Comment: *Humane* is the term I'd use.

Answer (score 1):

You answered your own question in the last line of your example, **gentle**.

> gentle: having or showing a kind and quiet nature; not harsh or violent. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gentle)
>
> *He remained gentle toward animals and humankind*. ([I was Amish: a personal story of an Amish girl and her life](https://books.google.fr/books?id=niJgKDlDZf4C&pg=PA95&lpg=PA95&dq=%22gentle+toward+animals%22&source=bl&ots=T2pm1gVh9R&sig=6oYEh6ENmexEtR8uPImbFnKKags&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAWoVChMIupPBvfC3yAIVTJwaCh1xPwqh#v=onepage&q=%22gentle%20toward%20animals%22&f=false))

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned ‘all living things.’, you can hyphenate common affection words, such as ones listed here, with ‘omni-’ to mean ‘all’.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/omni-

Edit

Actually, I even found the exact word for your requested definition, ‘omnibenevolent’.

From OED,

> omnibenevolent adj.  [ < omni- comb. form + benevolent adj., after omnipotent adj., omniscient adj. (see quot. 1679)] benevolent towards all; infinitely benevolent.

Also, http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/omnibenevolent.

Answer (score 0):

'good hombres'
'humans'
'nice people'

No, sorry. I think humane, although a little anthropocentric, covers the load.