# What do you call a person who is regionally unbiased?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, american-english, word-order, antonyms

What do you call a person who is regionally unbiased and has reasonable love/like for all people from other regions and countries/world? Something like someone who loves all people, not just of his own state within a country.  a loyal and disinterested supporter of all countries. Very obsessed with the whole world in a positive way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [People who treat living things with kindness and love: word/term](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/279072/people-who-treat-living-things-with-kindness-and-love-word-term)

Comment: One word strictly?

Answer (score 4):

cosmopolitan - both noun and adjective
cosmopolite - noun

> cosmopolitan
>  adj.
>   1. belonging to all the world; not limited to the politics, interests, or prejudices of one part of the world.
>  
> n.
>   4. a person who is free from local, provincial, or national bias or attachment; citizen of the world; cosmopolite. 
>  [Random House
>   Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/cosmopolitan)

> cosmopolitan
>   1. free from local, provincial, or national ideas, prejudices, or attachments; at home all over the world.
>   2. of or characteristic of a cosmopolite. noun
>   5.a person who is free from local, provincial, or national bias or attachment; citizen of the world; cosmopolite.
>  [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cosmopolitan)

> "Cosmopolitanism is the ideology that all human beings belong to a
>   single community, based on a shared morality." 
>  "Contemporary
>   usage defines the term as 'citizen of the world'."
>   [Cosmopolitanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmopolitanism#Definitions)

From what I've seen it may be related to global or world citizen:

> In general, a world citizen is a person who places global citizenship
>   above any nationalistic or local identities and relationships.
>
> Albert Einstein described himself as a world citizen and supported the
>   idea throughout his life, famously saying "Nationalism is an
>   infantile disease. It is the measles of mankind."
>
> [Global citizenship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_citizenship#World_citizen)

Answer (score -1):

A saint, like Mother Teressa.

An earthling.

A philanthropist.

A humanist.

Comment: Use citations in answers, if you please.